# converting a certain time format into a Date Object

Tags: javascript, date, countdown

I get this timestamp from an API  "2015-04-03T19:04:00" and every week it will be updated. I want to use [countdown.js](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and I have played around with it with the date in this format `new Date(year, month, days, hour, minutes)`...

it works:

```
$('.countTime').countdown({until : new Date(year, month, days, hour, minutes)})
```

basically I want to know the best way to convertthe string from the API to the date object I think that countdown.js accepts above. Do i split up the string into arrays by dashes and colons and delete the "T"? or is there a JavaScript function to convert the formats? Also I am concerned about it saying 19:04 when I was experimenting with it I used 12 hours not 24 hours. I wonder If I put in 19:04 and get the correct countdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Date('2015-04-03T19:04:00')`